# How to find a bayes risk

Tags: statistics, bayesian, risk-assessment

Let $X$ follows a normal distribution with parameters $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$. Let a prior for $\theta$ be a Normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $b^2$. How can I find the Bayes risk of this task? I know how to find a Bayes estimator, but I am confused about how can I find the Bayes risk using this estimator.

$$\bar{\theta} = \frac{b^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times X + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times \mu$$
$$Risk = \mathbb{V}  \Bigl[ \frac{b^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times X + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times \mu\Bigr] + \Bigl[ \theta - \mathbb{E}\Bigl( \frac{b^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times X + \frac{\sigma^2}{b^2+\sigma^2} \times \mu\Bigr)\Bigr]^2$$
Thank you!

Comment: Please show some effort in your post. For example, what is your estimator, and how did you compute it?

Comment: @MatthewH. I showed my findings for this question. I was wondering if you could help me to understand what to do next.